# jQuery find elements with value = x

Tags: jquery, find, attr

I need to remove element that have `value="123"`. I know that all elements with different values are located in `#attached_docs`, but I don't know how to select element with `value="123"`.

```
$('#attached_docs').find ... .remove();
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

If the value is hardcoded in the source of the page using the `value` attribute then you can

```
$('#attached_docs :input[value="123"]').remove();
```

or

```
$('#attached_docs :input').filter(function(){return this.value=='123'}).remove();
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/RcwXh/2/

Comment: what to do if instead of '123' i have an array..?

Comment: @JayMomaya then use the second version with the `filter` and inside return `array_var.includes(this.value)`

Answer (score 23):

Value exactly equal to 123:

```
jQuery("#attached_docs[value='123']")
```

Full reference: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5):

Use the following selector.

```
$('#attached_docs [value=123]').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

```
$("[id=attached_docs][value=123]")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#attached_docs [value="123"]').find ... .remove();
```

it should do your need
however, you cannot duplicate id! remember it

Comment: Good note about the id

Answer (score 2):

```
$(selector).filter(function(){return this.value==yourval}).remove();
```