# Multiple attribute jQuery selector not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

Hi I am trying to get all hidden fields on page with jQuery which have class name that I specify and have value of true. For this I am using following jQuery selector

```
$("input[class='EditModeStatus'][value='true']");
```

Here I want to get all hidden fields with class name "EditModeStatus" and have value of "true". This selector works fine in Mozilla and Chome but when I am testing it in IE8 it's not working. What will be issue in this?

Thanks

Comment: can you share a html markup which is not working

Comment: If you have multiple classes assigned to those elements, you will need to use `$("input[class*='EditModeStatus'][value='true']");`, the asterisk indicates `contains` not `equals` (only), this is also assuming they have a `value` attribute.

Comment: older IE has issues with getting any attribute where the property name is something else, for instance `getAttribute('class')` doesn't work in IE, but in all other browsers, but for some reason `getAttribute('className')` works in older IE, but not in other browsers, so I'm guessing that's the issue. Why not just do `$("input.EditModeStatus[value='true']");` instead

Comment: Do you have a `DOCTYPE`? [This page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) says you need it

Comment: Mentioned jquery selector is not working. Html for hidden field is like this <input type="hidden" class="EditModeStatus"></input> When edit mode is ON I assign value='true' indicating edit mode is ON and when done I assign value='false' indicating edit mode is OFF

Comment: you could look into this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6732402/3244925 `$("input.EditModeStatus").filter(...)`

Comment: Thank you all and @Nico O. By using $("input.EditModeStatus").filter(...) it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for your valuable replies.

Instead of following selector

```
$("input[class='EditModeStatus'][value='true']")
```

I used this

```
var IsEditModeOn = $("input.EditModeStatus").filter(function () { return this.value == 'true' }).length > 0;
```

and it works in all browsers.